# SQL left join copy non-existent results to null result

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, null, left-join

I have a table such that user A belongs to department 1. user B belongs to department 1. user A has links to rights x,y,z (in another table). user B has no rights.

I want to get rights of user B such that when null then return rights of user A since they are under the same department!! When user B has rights, then return found rights only so that user A and user B have different rights. So no rights means get group rights, else keep specific rights.

So far I got to the point of simply getting null for User B through left join.So User A has rights and User B has nulls. I want User B to return same results for User A. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? PostgreSQL, Oracle, SQL Server, MySQL, ...? You should always tag the DBMS with SQL questions. Moreover you should have shown your query.

Comment: What if you have multiple users in the same department with different sets of rights?

Comment: @ThorstenKettner its SQL Server. Is it tagged appropriately now? My query is somewhat more elaborate so I just extracted what I wanted to achieve. Also please note that I have edited my question to reflect the right requirements.

Comment: @GordonLinoff, I missed that part, added now. See if that answers your question please.

Comment: Please read & act on [mcve].

Comment: @philipxy Right and my apologies for not getting it right first time. Sometimes time pressure gets you, but at least I did end up using an answer that was provided to me before I even fixed the question so it seems that it wasn't that bad after all.

Comment: HI. This is only marginally better; you mostly unclearly repeat what you already unclearly said. But it still not clear. Eg Does "group" mean "department"? Eg Are A and/or B inputs? Eg you *don't* clarify "What if you have multiple users in the same department with different sets of rights?" The answers *guessed*. But they should have commented & downvoted & close voted instead. (And only one *clearly said* what they guessed.) Guesses lead to answering confusion--*look!*'; an unclear question is not a question. Lack of MCVE is a close reason--https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/333952/3404097.

Comment: Hi. This is littel better; you mostly unclearly repeat what you already unclearly said. But it still not clear. Eg Does "group" mean "department"? Eg Are A and/or B inputs? Eg you don't clarify "What if you have multiple users in the same department with different sets of rights?" The answers guessed. But they should have commented & downvoted & close voted instead. (And only one clearly said what they guessed.) Guesses lead to answering confusion--look at this page's comments! An unclear question is not a question. Lack of MCVE is a close reason--meta.stackoverflow.com/q/333952/3404097.

Comment: Hi Philipxy. I am the OP seeking help. If at least one person gives me the answer I was looking for and I find out it actually answers my question fully and correctly than it's useless you come and tell me you did not understand it. The question was as clear as it could be. In fact @ThorstenKettner understood it and gave a great answer. It would have taken me and fellow experts much more time trying to figure out the entire schema consisting of 5 tables just for rights and 3 tables for users and groups. So thanks for your input but everything went as expected, you can stop commenting now!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So there are two possible situations:

1. A user has rights. You want to show these rights for the user.
2. A user has no rights. You want to show all rights of the users in the user's department.

This is a bit queer, but well ... You already know how to left join the user's rights. A null right means the user has no rights. On this condition you want to join the department rights - another outer join.

```
select u.userid, coalesce(ur.right, dr.right)
from users u
left join rights ur on ur.userid = u.userid
left join
(
  select distinct u.deptid, r.right
  from users u
  join rights r on r.userid = u.userid
) dr on ur.right is null and dr.deptid = u.deptid;
```

Comment: Thanks Thorsten and your answer looks quite on the right track. Due to the lack of time I have on this, I came up with the simplest explanation I could think of. I edited my question as I missed a crucial part out. I want both situations to co-exist however the result of your query still gets me all rights for User B when User B has specific rights set!

Comment: Works for me. Demo here: http://rextester.com/EKPJN11375. In that demo there are three users in department 10: user A, B, and C. A and C have specific rights, B has no specific rights. Seems to work just fine.

Comment: I ended up using this query and it did work as intended. The others were just as fine but I learnt how to use coalesce through this and there was no hard-coding in it.

Comment: @JustinFarrugia . . . That's fine.  You are the OP and can accept any answer that you consider to be the best.

Answer (score 1):

An other query using sub-queries, you should replace the value **2** with the desired user id :

```
SELECT
  Rights.userid, Rights.rightname
FROM
  Rights
WHERE
  Rights.userid IN (
    IF( 
      (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Rights WHERE Rights.userid = 2)>0 , 
      2, 
      (SELECT 
         GROUP_CONCAT(Users.id SEPARATOR ', ') 
         FROM Users 
         WHERE depart LIKE (SELECT Users.depart FROM Users WHERE Users.id = 2) 
         GROUP BY Users.depart
      ))
  );
```

[The complete code in SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/8cc242/2)

Comment: Thanks Korteby, your query helped me understand how I could have achieved the same result with an actual condition. I would have used a case (maybe it would have made it more readable), but good effort.

Answer (score 1):

I would simply do:

```
select r.*
from rights r
where r.user = 'B'
union all
select r.*
from rights r
where r.user = 'A' and
      not exists (select 1 from rights r2 where r2.user = 'B');
```

Comment: Thanks Gordon. This looks like it's a literal way to address the problem as the users are hard-coded. Also if both users have set rights, I believe the union all will get me all rights for User B which is not what I'm after. Only when null, I get User A rights, else User B.

Comment: @JustinFarrugia . . . What does "null" have to do with "no rights".  If both users have rights, then the `where` clause prevents any (additional) rights from "A" being in the result set.  This does exactly what you are asking for, as I understand the question.

Comment: Thanks for your replies; technically you are correct but mine was an example question not a literal one. I was after a more general solution like the one from Thorsten Kettner below.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I understood it: it doesn't really matter which right certain user has, as all users from the same department share the same rights. If that's so, here's one option: I've created *dummy* tables (no constraints or additional columns) just to show what I meant. It was executed on Oracle, but should be OK elsewhere (at least, I hope so). If your database doesn't support the WITH factoring clause, just move that SELECT into an inline view. If you don't know how, say so.

```
SQL> create table users (id_user varchar2(1), id_dept number);

Table created.

SQL> create table rights (id_user varchar2(1), id_right varchar2(1));

Table created.

SQL> insert all
  2    into users values ('A', 1)
  3    into users values ('B', 1)
  4    into users values ('C', 2)
  5    into rights values ('A', 'x')
  6    into rights values ('A', 'y')
  7    into rights values ('C', 'z')
  8  select * From dual;

6 rows created.

SQL>
SQL> with dept_rights as
  2    (select distinct u.id_dept, r.id_right
  3     from users u join rights r on r.id_user = u.id_user
  4    )
  5  select u.id_user, dr.id_right
  6  from users u join dept_rights dr on dr.id_dept = u.id_Dept
  7  order by 1, 2;

ID_USER    ID_RIGHT
---------- ----------
A          x
A          y
B          x
B          y
C          z

SQL>
```